# How do I resize a SKSpriteNode as a background to perfectly fit the screen in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm using swift to make my first game and I have a background image that I need to perfectly fit the screen. Right now the image is zoomed in.

In my GameViewController.swift I have added:

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

Also, In my GameScene.swift I have added:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

let CKBackground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CKBackground")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    CKBackground.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    CKBackground.size.height = self.size.height
    CKBackground.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    self.addChild(CKBackground)
```

The background is zoomed in no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just needed to add a size.width also!